# Get X509 Certificate from Azure Keyvault to use in a REST call

Tags: rest, x509certificate, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to get a certificate from Azure Keyvault, and then use it to call a REST API which requires a certificate for its authentication.

I've tried doing this locally - I have the `.pfx` file on disk, I load it into a byte array, and then create my certificate from it:

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(path), password);
```

and then use that certificate in RestSharp to do my REST call:

```
IRestClient client = new RestClient(url);
client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection { x509 };

var request = new RestRequest(lastUrlPart, Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    // read out the response and process it
}
```

works like a charm.

Now I'm trying to do the same, but fetching the certificate from Azure Keyvault. I've created an app registration in Azure AD, created my keyvault, and gave my app registration's service identity access to the keyvault. I've uploaded my certificate into the keyvault. So far, so good.

I've found this code to fetch the certificate from the Keyvault:

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var kv = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
                                        {
                                            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
                                            var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientAppId, clientSecret);
                                            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

                                            if (result == null)
                                            {
                                                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
                                            }

                                            return result.AccessToken;
                                        });

string certIdentifier = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/certificates/Certificate-TEST/14753af7586445fe9d57efa136ac090c";

var vaultCertificate = kv.GetCertificateAsync(certIdentifier).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This also works - I can access the keyvault with my app identity, and I can fetch the certificate from the keyvault, and the X.509 thumbprint is valid - but now this is a `CertificateBundle` from the `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models` namespace - how do I "convert" that into a "regular" `X509Certificate2` object so that I can use it for the REST call?

I've tried several things, for instance

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(vaultCertificate.Cer);
```

but nothing works - when I place my REST call, I get a HTTP 403 - Forbidden error back....

What am I missing?? How can I fetch a certificate from Azure Keyvault in a format that can be used to authenticate in a subsequent REST call??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course - right after I posted this question, I stumbled across the solution....

This [blog post by Matt Small](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/07/03/azure-key-vault-certificates-are-secrets) explains it in great details (and with really nice, and **working** code examples, too).

Basically, in order to use the certificate for authentication, you need to have the private key, too - and when you do a `GetCertificateAsync`, you only get back the public information of the certificate.

You need to fetch the certificate *as a secret* and then base64 decode it - then you get all the necessary bits and the REST call works.

GOSH !! Why is this so darn convoluted?? Why can't there just be a `includePrivate: bool` parameter on the `GetCertificateAsync` call to tell Keyvault if you need just the public, or public *and* private parts of your certificate?

You store a certificate - but to get it, you need to fetch a secret .... that's just all wrong, and violates the **Basic Principle Of Least Surprise!** MS, if you're listening - this API really needs a bit more work to make it more approachable to novice Azure devs!!

And PS: this of course also means the user/identity you're using to access the keyvault now needs **permissions** to read secrets - not just certificates.....

Comment: Hey great. Stumbled into this issue myself and can follow you all along the way of this API.

Comment: This is exactly why i thought there cant be a way to get cert with private key and want to just read before i try. This makes complete sense. Azure should not have an API to get private key, how is it a private key then. Right way is to have azure make your cert available to your compute at runtime.

Comment: MS please read this, there is no sense to expose a CertificateClient which cannot handle or provide any method to give back a complete X509. Way to go Marc!!

If the problem is permission itself, there are a lot of ways to approach it on the client itself

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var cert = kvc.GetCertificateAsync(baseUrl, "Demo").ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var cert_content = cert.Cer;
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(cert_content);
```

You can easily get the raw bytes of your certificate from the `CertificateBundle`, and then use the raw bytes to create your X509Certificate2 instance.

Comment: I had tried that myself (and it's part of my post, too) - but that **didn't** work - see my response - that's the way to go.

Comment: It seems that you need the private key. But, you can only retrieve the public certificate from the Azure Key Vault Certificate.

Comment: So, the only solution should be using the secret to store the whole pfx file content, and then get it and use it to create an X509Certificate2 object.

Comment: The certificate is stored as a **certificate** in the Azure Keyvault - but you must retrieve **as a secret** in order to get both public and private components of it. I know - weird and not really clear - I hope MS is listening and improving this Keyvault client API !!

Comment: Yes. I think so too.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it with the generally recommended approach of using the secret e.g:

```cs
var creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var keyVaultUrl = new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net");
var certClient = new CertificateClient(keyVaultUrl, creds);

var certResp = certClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);
var identifer = new KeyVaultSecretIdentifier(certResp.Value.SecretId);

var secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, creds);
var secretResp = secretClient.GetSecret(identifer.Name, identifer.Version);

byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secretResp.Value.Value);

var cert = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes);
```

But then I stumbled across `DownloadCertificate()` which seems to work with less code, i.e.:

```cs
var creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var keyVaultUrl = new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net");
var certClient = new CertificateClient(keyVaultUrl, creds);

var cert = certClient.DownloadCertificate(certificateName);
```

As far as I can tell it works fine in my tests, I'd be interested to know why this isn't the recommended approach.

## Update

When I released this code to production I hit:
*WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified*

After a bit of digging around, I came across these questions:

1. [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840825/cryptographicexception-was-unhandled-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file)
2. [X509Certificate Constructor Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951729/x509certificate-constructor-exception/10048789#10048789)

It looks like I could solve the problem with this, but in the end I stuck with the original code, because I don't like configuring special setups for a given site - it always comes back to bite.

My final solution looks like this:

```cs
public static X509Certificate2 LoadFromKeyVault(string keyVaultName, string certificateName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(keyVaultName)} cannot be empty");
    }

    var creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    var keyVaultUrl = new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net");
    var certClient = new CertificateClient(keyVaultUrl, creds);

    var certResp = certClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);
    var identifer = new KeyVaultSecretIdentifier(certResp.Value.SecretId);

    var secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, creds);
    var secretResp = secretClient.GetSecret(identifer.Name, identifer.Version);

    byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secretResp.Value.Value);

    var result = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes, string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    return result;
}
```